# UIPickerView jumps over values in array while scroll it

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have trouble with a UIPickerView. I have an app where a UITextField’s inputView is set as a UIPickerView. When it appears, everything is ok. The row’s title is correct but when I scroll down to next element, somehow it is passing over a few of the array’s values and stops on wrong value. At the end, the title isn’t equal to its actual value.

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

...

// MARK: - Race outlet
@IBOutlet weak var raceTextField: UITextField!

// MARK: - "Purchased" column outlets
@IBOutlet weak var purchasedStrTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var purchasedDexTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var purchasedConTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var purchasedIntTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var purchasedWisTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var purchasedChaTextField: UITextField!

...

// MARK: - "Actual" column outlets
@IBOutlet weak var actualStrLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var actualDexLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var actualConLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var actualIntLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var actualWisLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var actualChaLabel: UILabel!

...

// MARK: - Constants
let pickerView = UIPickerView()

// MARK: - Variables
var raceArray = [Race]()
var selectedTextField: Int!

// MARK: - Lifecicle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configurePickerView()
    congigureTextFields()
    createRaces()

...
}

...

// MARK: - Methods

func createRaces() {
    let human = Race(str: 0, dex: 0, con: 0, int: 0, wis: 0, cha: 0,
                     raceDesrciption: "Human (add +2 to any one ability)", raceMod: true)

    let elf = Race(str: 0, dex: 2, con: -2, int: 2, wis: 0, cha: 0,
                   raceDesrciption: "Elf", raceMod: false)

    let halfElf = Race(str: 0, dex: 0, con: 0, int: 0, wis: 0, cha: 0,
                       raceDesrciption: "Half-Elf (add +2 to any one ability)", raceMod: true)

    let dwarf = Race(str: 0, dex: 0, con: 2, int: 0, wis: 2, cha: -2,
                     raceDesrciption: "Dwarf", raceMod: false)

    let hafling = Race(str: -2, dex: 2, con: 0, int: 0, wis: 0, cha: 2,
                       raceDesrciption: "Hafling", raceMod: false)

    let gnome = Race(str: -2, dex: 0, con: 2, int: 0, wis: 0, cha: 2,
                     raceDesrciption: "Gnome", raceMod: false)

    let halfOrc = Race(str: 0, dex: 0, con: 0, int: 0, wis: 0, cha: 0,
                       raceDesrciption: "Half-Orc (add +2 to any one ability)", raceMod: true)

    let other = Race(str: 0, dex: 0, con: 0, int: 0, wis: 0, cha: 0,
                     raceDesrciption: "Other", raceMod: true)

    raceArray.append(human)
    raceArray.append(elf)
    raceArray.append(halfElf)
    raceArray.append(dwarf)
    raceArray.append(hafling)
    raceArray.append(gnome)
    raceArray.append(halfOrc)
    raceArray.append(other)
}

/// Set parameters for specific race
func setDefaultPoints(_ selectedRace: String) {
    for item in raceArray {
        if selectedRace == item.raceDesrciption {
            raceModeStrTextField.text = "\(item.str!)"
            raceModeDexTextField.text = "\(item.dex!)"
            raceModeConTextField.text = "\(item.con!)"
            raceModeIntTextField.text = "\(item.int!)"
            raceModeWisTextField.text = "\(item.wis!)"
            raceModeChaTextField.text = "\(item.cha!)"

            setActualPointsForRace(item)
            switchRaceModTextTield(item.editableRaceMod)
        }
    }
}

/// Update "Actual points" labels
func setActualPointsForRace(_ race: Race) {
    actualStrLabel.text = "\(Int(lowPoweredValueLabel.text!)! - race.str)"
    strLabel.text = actualStrLabel.text

    actualDexLabel.text = "\(Int(lowPoweredValueLabel.text!)! - race.dex)"
    dexLabel.text = actualDexLabel.text

    actualConLabel.text = "\(Int(lowPoweredValueLabel.text!)! - race.con)"
    conLabel.text = actualConLabel.text

    actualIntLabel.text = "\(Int(lowPoweredValueLabel.text!)! - race.int)"
    intLabel.text = actualIntLabel.text

    actualWisLabel.text = "\(Int(lowPoweredValueLabel.text!)! - race.wis)"
    wisLabel.text = actualWisLabel.text

    actualChaLabel.text = "\(Int(lowPoweredValueLabel.text!)! - race.cha)"
    chaLabel.text = actualChaLabel.text
}

func setTotalPointsWith(_ points: Int) {
    let currentValue = Int(totalPointValueLabel.text!)!
    totalPointValueLabel.text = "\(currentValue + points)"
}
}
```

Here is my `UIPickerView` code:

```
extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

func configurePickerView() {
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if selectedTextField == 1 {
        print(raceArray.count)
        return raceArray.count

    } else {
        print(purchaseValues.count)
        return purchaseValues.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    switch selectedTextField {
    case 1:
        raceTextField.text = raceArray[row].raceDesrciption
        return raceArray[row].raceDesrciption

    case 2:
        purchasedStrTextField.text = "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"
        return "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"

    case 3:
        purchasedDexTextField.text = "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"
        return "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"

    case 4:
        purchasedConTextField.text = "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"
        return "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"

    case 5:
        purchasedIntTextField.text = "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"
        return "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"

    case 6:
        purchasedWisTextField.text = "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"
        return "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"

    case 7:
        purchasedChaTextField.text = "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"
        return "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"

    default:
        print("no value")
    }

    return nil
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    switch selectedTextField {
    case 1:
        setDefaultPoints(raceArray[row].raceDesrciption)

    case 2:
        actualStrLabel.text = "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"
        setTotalPointsWith(purchaseValues[row].1)

    case 3:
        actualDexLabel.text = "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"
        setTotalPointsWith(purchaseValues[row].1)

    case 4:
        actualConLabel.text = "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"
        setTotalPointsWith(purchaseValues[row].1)

    case 5:
        actualIntLabel.text = "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"
        setTotalPointsWith(purchaseValues[row].1)

    case 6:
        actualWisLabel.text = "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"
        setTotalPointsWith(purchaseValues[row].1)

    case 7:
        actualChaLabel.text = "\(purchaseValues[row].0)"
        setTotalPointsWith(purchaseValues[row].1)

    default:
        print("no value")
    }
}
}
```

TextFields configure:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

func congigureTextFields() {
    raceTextField.inputView = pickerView
    purchasedStrTextField.inputView = pickerView
    purchasedDexTextField.inputView = pickerView
    purchasedConTextField.inputView = pickerView
    purchasedIntTextField.inputView = pickerView
    purchasedWisTextField.inputView = pickerView
    purchasedChaTextField.inputView = pickerView

    raceTextField.delegate = self
    purchasedStrTextField.delegate = self
    purchasedDexTextField.delegate = self
    purchasedConTextField.delegate = self
    purchasedIntTextField.delegate = self
    purchasedWisTextField.delegate = self
    purchasedChaTextField.delegate = self
    raceModeStrTextField.delegate = self
    raceModeDexTextField.delegate = self
    raceModeConTextField.delegate = self
    raceModeIntTextField.delegate = self
    raceModeWisTextField.delegate = self
    raceModeChaTextField.delegate = self
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    selectedTextField = textField.tag
    pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
}
}
```

And `purchaseValues` array:

```
let purchaseValues = [
(7, -4),
(8, -2),
(9, -1),
(10, 0),
(11, 1),
(12, 2),
(13, 3),
(14, 5),
(15, 7),
(16, 10),
(17, 13),
(18, 17)
]
```

Comment: The output of the print statements is irrelevant. You can't make any assumptions on the order that `titleForRow` will be called. What is your actually issue with the picker view? Based on your code, the picker should be showing the keys from your tuples in the correct order.

Comment: @rmaddy
I'm sorry for the mess in the console! The thing is that picker's `numberOfRowsInComponent` return array's count 28 times. I have no idea why is it so.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many times it is called or in what order. Does your picker actually show the correct data? Don't worry about your print statements.

Comment: I think it doesn't. Because then I have to assign key's value to specific `UILabel` when scrolling `UIPickerView`. And in the end it shows correct title in `UIPicker`'s row, but assign incorrect value to `UILabel`.

Comment: If your problem is with updating the label from the picker then please show that code in your question. The picker view code you have so far is fine.

Comment: I added code. `purchaseValues` - is the same as `array` in my earlier post.

Comment: Can you please post one set of code that fits together. You now have two `titleForRow` methods and the new one references variables you haven't mentioned before. This is impossible to debug.

Comment: I edited my post so you can check it! Thank you!

Comment: Do not update any labels or text fields or anything else inside `titleForRow`. Do only one thing in that method - return a string.

Comment: Ok, thank you! But could you please tell me why I have to do nothing in `titleForRow` except of return string?

Comment: Because that is the only purpose of `titleForRow`. It's one and only job is to tell the picker view what title to use for the requested row.

Comment: Single responsibility principle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rmaddy said: "...the only purpose of `titleForRow`. It's one and only job is to tell the picker view what title to use for the requested row." - this is where I made mistake. Thanks a lot!